# How to increment value in an object, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to increment a value in an object by 1, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have a mongoose Schema set up as follows:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  userId: String,
  items: Object
});
```

Which stores data as follows:

```
items: {
  "1234": 1,
  "5678": 4
}
```

Where `1234` and `5678` are item IDs, and `1`, `4` are the quanitity of that item the user has. As an example, I need to increment `"1234": 1` by 1, to return `"1234": 2`, and leaving `"5678" : 4` unchanged.
I have tried:

```
let newItem = "1234";
let userProfile = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ 
  userId: userID
}, {
  $inc: {
    items: {
      newItem: 1
    }
  }
});
```

Which returns an error: `The field 'items' must be an array but is of type object`.

I have also tried:

```
  $inc: {
    "items":  {
      newItem: 1
    }
  }
```

Which returns: `Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {items: { newItem: 1 }}`, and:

```
$inc: {
  `items.${newItem}`: 1 
}
```

Which returns

```
`items.${newItem}`: 1 
^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected template string
```

Comment: Use dot notation to refer to fields in embedded documents, like `{$inc:{"items.1234":1}}`

Comment: have to use the variable newItem, as it is input by the user. I have posted a solution though. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. To use a variable in the keyname, wrap a template in []

```
$inc: {
  [`items.${newItem}`]: 1 
}
```